# Most efficient way to enter data in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops

I'm making a program which has an option to let the user enter data into an array.
For example the option will ask the user to enter the make and model of a car which
will then be stored as an element in an array. I want to know how I can let the program enter
the next car as a different element each loop. For example:

Loop 1:
Enter car details
( stored as myArray[1] )

*back to start*

Loop 2: Enter car details
( stored as myArray[2] )

etc..

what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Arrays died long back. Use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/). Might be [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ?

Comment: doesn't answer the question though

Comment: You have answers now, Mine is just a comment(suggestion) :)

Comment: do you know exactly how many cars you have?

Comment: yes there are 10 cars

Comment: please see my answer. I make some asymptions about your code, if it's wrong let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have object named Car, that contains it's make and mode.
Also I suppose you have method `Car readCar()` that creats new Car somehow.
See code snipped that creates arraya of Car objects and populates it:

```
int carsNumber = 10;//number of cars
Car [] cars = new Car[carsNumber];//creates empty array (10 null)
for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
{
    Car c = readCar(make,model);//creates Car somehow
    cars[i] = c;//populates current car in array, i++ command will move to next index
}
```

Comment: thank you very much exactly what I needed, just one question where does that 'c' come from at the end?

Comment: see previuos line Car c = readCar(make,model);I suppose you know how to create Car object from input data

Comment: sorry missed that part ahah thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
while (userinput!="finish") {
 String detail1 = Console.readline();
 String details2 = Console.readLine();
 Car c = new Car(details1, details2);
 carList.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Car details?? Better make a class Car and fields accordingly, override hashcode and equals and use Set for sorting purpose.